# Parse JsonSchema into io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have spring boot app that provides openapi. I've used Swagger. I have a file that stores jsonSchema and I wanna to parse it into io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema to add it into Swagger. I can't find any existing solutions. Does any spring boot library supports this functionality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring web MVC HATEOS endpoints, then you can directly use the https://springdoc.org/. Example: @RequestMapping, @GetMapping, etc.

Springdoc-openapi comes with ui and open api v3 docs generation.

IF not, and you prefer to use JaxRS2 to configure your RESTful endpoints, then use the `<groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId><artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>`, and register your resources using `JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig and include  io.swagger.v3.integration.sources` for jaxrs2 scanning.